How to make memoize and tcolorbox work together?
I am exploring memoize to externalize some part of my documents.
I would like to combine this package with tcolorbox.
But when I use these packages together I get LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
Here is a MWE
\documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{tcolorbox}
      \tcbuselibrary{skins,theorems}
   \usepackage{pseudo}
      \newtcbtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}{pseudo/booktabs, float}{alg}

   \usepackage{memoize} %
      \mmzset{
         auto={tcolorbox}{nomemoize},
         auto={algorithm}{nomemoize},
         auto={pseudo}{nomemoize},
      }

\begin{document}
   Memoize will automatically externalize TikZ:\\
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node(node)
      [align=center,draw]
      {TikZ\\pictures};
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \begin{algorithm}{Euclid's algorithm, \pr{Euclid}(a, b)}{euclid}
      \begin{pseudo}
         a line of pseudo-code
      \end{pseudo}
  \end{algorithm}

  This is a reference to alg.\ref{alg:euclid}. 

\end{document}

Memoize's documentation is mentioning uses with floats, but the documentation itself is using both memoize and tcolorbox together.
But I do not understand how it does.
So how to make memoize and tcolorbox work together (with float environments) ?

You are loading memoize too late. It must be loaded before tikz etc. The following produces a single externalised image, extracting and including it on the second run.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{memoize}
\mmzset{
  auto={tcolorbox}{nomemoize},
  auto={algorithm}{nomemoize},
  auto={pseudo}{nomemoize},
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,theorems}
\usepackage{pseudo}
\newtcbtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}{pseudo/booktabs, float}{alg}


\begin{document}
Memoize will automatically externalize TikZ:\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(node)
  [align=center,draw]
  {TikZ\\pictures};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{algorithm}{Euclid's algorithm, \pr{Euclid}(a, b)}{euclid}
  \begin{pseudo}
    a line of pseudo-code
  \end{pseudo}
\end{algorithm}

This is a reference to alg.\ref{alg:euclid}.

\end{document}

You can also subject some tcolorboxes to memoization, but they will not all work.
